# Check if variable can be cast against a dynamic datatype

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, types, datatable

I am creating an import application in VB.NET for an SQL Server 2008 database. I am trying to make the import as generic as possible to reduce maintenance in the future. Therefore it gets all available columns from a preset list of tables in which they can import into.

The main problem is that now I have gotten to the point where I am doing error trapping. I am currently try to check to see whether a value that is being imported is castable as the data type of the field in the database. For example, if you want to import a date into the database but you mistakenly put an address field instead, I want to pick this up and alert the user.

So, I have a VB datatable with the same schema as the database table and a value which I would like to go into the datatable. Below is what I have already (which is not alot):

```
    Private Sub SetValue(TargetDataTable As DataTable, ColumnName as String, Value as string)
       Dim DBType as Type = TargetDataTable.Columns(ColumnName).Datatype

       ????
    End Sub
```

I have done some research about reflection but it still requires me to define datatypes. Are there any other ways of doing this?

Comment: Not tested, but you can try using [`DynamicObject.TryConvert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.tryconvert.aspx) or you can try using [`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there is a way to do this automatically for any type, but according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype.aspx) there are 18 types that are supported which should be manageable.

```
Private Sub SetValue(TargetDataTable As DataTable, ColumnName As String, Value As String)

    Dim DBType As Type = TargetDataTable.Columns(ColumnName).DataType

    Dim valueint As Integer
    Dim valuebln As Boolean

    If DBType Is GetType(Integer) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(Value, valueint) = False Then
        'Has error
    End If

    If DBType Is GetType(Boolean) AndAlso Boolean.TryParse(Value, valuebln) = False Then
        'Has error
    End If

    '...

End Sub
```